# trying to make tkinter output full string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple tkinter character converter. I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from numpy import binary_repr

window = Tk()
window.title("CHARACTER CONVERTER")
window.geometry('600x500')

frame = Frame(window)
input = Entry(frame,width = 50)
input.pack()
text = Text(window, width=40, height=40, wrap = "none", font = ('ariel',13),foreground='red', background='black')

def ASC():
    global result
    result = input.get()
    len(result)
    for char in result:
        ascii = ord(char)
        P = (char, "\t", ascii)    
    text.insert(tk.END, P)

button2 = Button(frame, text = 'ASCII',bg='black',fg='red', command = ASC)

button2.pack(side = LEFT)
frame.pack(side = TOP)
text.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

When I try using the button for the `ASC` callback, it only shows the information for the last letter of the string in the `text` field. How do I make it show information for the whole string?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think carefully about the logic of the code. When `ASC` runs, what does `text.insert(tk.END, P)` do? How much text will be inserted by that? Therefore, how many times should it run - just once, or several times (once for each `char in result`)? Therefore, should it be outside the loop, or inside? Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to find problems like this yourself before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please also read [ask] and [mre]. When posting, try to show only the code that is relevant to the problem. Try to make something that someone else can copy and paste to show the problem, but which doesn't include any extra unused functionality. When writing the question, try to use complete, well organized sentences, and [avoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721) asking vaguely for ["help"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236).

Comment: thank you,you game me a lot to think about i will definitely  take your advice

Answer (score 0):

It is because you execute `text.insert(tk.END, P)` after the for loop, so it only inserts the result of `P` in last iteration of the for loop.

You need to put `text.insert(tk.END, P)` inside the for loop instead:

```py
def ASC():
    global result
    result = input.get()
    len(result)
    for char in result:
        ascii = ord(char)
        P = f'{char}\t{ascii}\n'
        text.insert(tk.END, P)
```

Comment: thank you it seems so obvious now,  I will definitely do more research in the future

Comment: @EyesOfSiva If it solves your problem, consider to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would it better if we used **Python 3.8 by using Walrus**?

```
def ASC():   
    len(result := input.get())
    for char in result:
        ascii = ord(char)
        P = f'{char}\t{ascii}\n'
        text.insert(tk.END, P)
```

That would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the feedback i will mess around with the code you uploaded